# Django user get logout if more than one user login

Tags: django

If i login with user1 & in another system login with user2 then user1 automatically get logout. the reason is django_session entry get deleted from database of first user i.e. user1.  I am using Django 2.0.5.

following code from setting.py -

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

]

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = 3600

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600

AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY = 3600

login.html

```html
<form action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    {{ form.username.errors }}
    {{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    {{ form.password.errors }}
    {{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/admin/" />
  </div>
  {% url 'admin_password_reset' as password_reset_url %}
  {% if password_reset_url %}
  <div class="password-reset-link">
    <a href="{{ password_reset_url }}">{% trans 'Forgotten your password or username?' %}</a>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="submit-row">
    <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  </div>
</form>
```

i am using django for backend & angular as a frontend. everything is working fine if single user accessing the url but if another user login on another system one of the user get logout among the current logged in user.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve and what error you are getting with your code.

Comment: I think django session auth allows multiple sessions. So add more code samples

Comment: I updated the question. any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just asking. Did you check the login view. Can you post it too.

Comment: using default django login template, question updated with login code.

Comment: Are you logging in these 2 users from the same IP address?

Comment: yes. I have multiple user.